# pandas transform function as argument

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Sorry for a longread, The question is actually much shorter than is seems to be.

Can anyone explain how function-typed argument of `pandas.core.groupby.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transorm` is being used?

I wrote this snippet to find out what arguments are fed into function:

```
def printer(x): print(''); print(type(x)); print(x); return x
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,2], 'B':[3,4,5], 'C':[6,7,8]})
print('initial dataframe:', df, '\n===TRANSFORM LOG BEGIN===', sep='\n')
df2 = df.groupby('A').transform(printer)
print('\n===TRANSFORM LOG END===', 'final dataframe:', df2, sep='\n')
```

The output is (split into chunks)

1. ```
   initial dataframe:
      A  B  C
   0  1  3  6
   1  1  4  7
   2  2  5  8
   ```

OK, move on

2. ```
   ===TRANSFORM LOG BEGIN===

   <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
   0    3
   1    4
   Name: B, dtype: int64
   ```

Apparently we got a group of values for column `B` with key (column `A` value) `1`. Carry on

3.

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
0    3
1    4
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

??. The same `Series` object is passed twice. The only justification that I could imagine is that there are two rows with column `A` equal to `1`, so for each occurrence of such a row we recompute our `transforming` function. Seems strange and inefficient, hardly to be true.

4.

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
0    6
1    7
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

That's analogous to p.2 for another column

5.

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
   B  C
0  3  6
1  4  7
```

Why there is no counterpart of p.3??

6.

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
   B  C
2  5  8
===TRANSFORM LOG END===
```

This is a counterpart to p.6 but why there is no one to p.2 for another grouping key?

7.

```
final dataframe:
   B  C
0  3  6
1  4  7
2  5  8
```

**TLDR**

Apart from strange behaviour, the main point is that the passed function gets both `Series` and `DataFrame` objects as arguments. Does it mean that it (function) must respect both types? Are there any restrictions on transformation type since the function is essentially called several times on the same values (`Series`, then `Dataframe` consisting of these `Series`), sort of reduce-like operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pandas is experimenting with the input (Series by Series or the whole DataFrame) to see if the function can be applied more efficiently. The notes from the [docstring](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py#L243):

> The current implementation imposes three requirements on f:
>
> - f must return a value that either has the same shape as the input   subframe or can be broadcast to the shape of the input subframe.   For
>   example, f returns a scalar it will be broadcast to have the   same
>   shape as the input subframe.
> - if this is a DataFrame, f must support application column-by-column   in the subframe. If f also supports application to the entire
>   subframe,   then a fast path is used starting from the second chunk.
> - f must not mutate groups. Mutation is not supported and may   produce unexpected results.

The second call to the same function is also about finding a faster path. You see the same behavior with [apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

> In the current implementation apply calls func twice on the first
> column/row to decide whether it can take a fast or slow code path.
> This can lead to unexpected behavior if func has side-effects, as they
> will take effect twice for the first column/row.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense and puts things in order:) Thank you!